# How to change URL in browser address bar with angularJS without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS, I'm working on a project. 
I'm calling an angular function on ng-click. the function is working fine but URL is not changing in the browser address bar while if I change the function in pure javascript and call the function. it changes the URL in the browser address bar without page reloading.

```
function pushAdd(page) {
    // alert("page");
    window.history.pushState("", "", "/account/" + page);
}
```

in angular function, I'm calling js function named pussAdd. when I use alert function within pushAdd() function it shows alert with page name. but the URL is not changing.

```
$scope.changeUrl = function (page) {
    /*my code which is working fine here*/
    pushAdd(page);
}
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve? You described two behaviors, but I don't see a question or desired state in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$location.path()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path) to change URL in *Angular way*:

```
angular.directive(
    'fooBar',
    [
        '$location',
        ($location) =>
            {
                restrict: 'EA',
                link: (scope) =>
                    scope.changeUrl = (page) => $location.path("/account/" + page)
            }
    ]
);
```

Comment: thank you for the response, I tried the solution given by you.  It's showing error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Comment: @madarauchiha Possible. It's written out of head, not actual code. But idea is the same: use `$location.path()` or `$location.url()`. Also consider using `$state.go()` to change state of your app.